# lcov html report coverage limits

Tags: code-coverage, lcov

Lcov has [genhtml](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/genhtml.1.php) tool which converts the lcov coverage info file into HTML report. It is possible to color code the results table- indicating low, medium and high coverage with following lcov configuration file options:
genhtml_hi_limit
genhtml_med_limit

However these limits seem to apply globally to all types of coverage metrics i.e. line, function and branch. Is there a way to set individual limits for the line, function and branch coverage metrics? Or can this be achieved with CSS somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although genhtml documentation describes only about the global limits, on inspecting the source, there is following limits than can be set in lcovrc file to set colors specific to coverage types.

genhtml_branch_hi_limit, genhtml_branch_med_limit

genhtml_function_hi_limit, genhtml_function_med_limit